Change in "new tab" behavior in Chrome--focus now on new tab?
In the last week or so, Chrome (up2date, Version 130.0.6723.117 (Official Build) (64-bit) ) has changed the way it focuses on new tabs.
Previously, I could CTRL+click or right-click and select "Open in New Tab" for a link, then have the new tab open for that link but Chrome would not switch to the new tab. (Basically, I'm just grabbing links I want to pursue in a moment and don't want to switch to them immediately 'till I've selected everything.)
However, in the last week (and I think this may be related to a Chrome update in that period), Chrome now opens the new tab but it also switches focus to the new tab. Is there a way to revert to the old behavior?
(Just tried FireFox to see if this behavior change was happening there, too. Nope, it's apparently just in Chrome.)

I'm on 131.0.6778.33 on WIndows and there's no such behavior

I'm on 130.0.6723.117 on Windows 11 and both ctrl-leftclick and rightclick then open in new tab do not switch to the new tab. Ctrl-shift-leftclick does switch to the new tab, though I think you'd notice if the shift key was stuck down.

Got it. Thank you both!! :)
