How To Remain On Current Tab When Opening Link In New Tab in Chrome
When using Chrome until recently, if I opened a link in a new tab, the focus remained on the original tab. This was true regardless of the method used to open the tab--context menu, ctrl-click, Vimium shift-f. Now, I believe since the last Chrome update, the focus automatically switches to the newly opened tab, regardless of the method used to open it. How can I open a link in a background tab?

Just for clarity (and future reference) what version of Chrome are you using?

There's been a similar one posted recently https://superuser.com/questions/1861261/change-in-new-tab-behavior-in-chrome-focus-now-on-new-tab You'll need to provide more details to find the culprit. Maybe some random extension upgraded for you both and causes this behavior.

Since posting this a few hours ago, I upgraded again to 131.0.6778.70, and tabs are once again opening as expected.
